# Passing html tables to a new page in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I tried to convert app engine generated output page into pdf, and had some problems.
First: I select the contents in `jQuery`.
Second: Send this `javascript` variable to a new python script
Third: In the new python script, using xhtml2pdf to the conversion.
However, I got confused in the Second step. Below is my approach:

HTML:

```
<div class="articles">
        <h2 class="model_header">PFAM Output</h2>
    <form>
        <table align="center">
            <!--end 04uberoutput_start-->
            <table class="out_chemical" width="550" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" colspan="5">
                        <div align="center">Chemical Inputs</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" width="250">
                        <div align="center">Variable</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" width="150">
                        <div align="center">Unit</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" width="150">
                        <div align="center">Value</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div align="center">Water Column Half life @20 &#8451</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div align="center">days</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div align="center">11</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var jq_html = $("div.articles").html();
  console.log(jq_html);
$('.getpdf').append('<tr style="display:none"><td><input name="extract" value="' + jq_html + '"></input></td></tr>');
$('.getpdf').append('<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Generate PDF"/></td></tr>');
})
```

new python script to do the conversion

```
   def post(self):
        form = cgi.FieldStorage()   
        extract = form.getvalue('extract')
        print extract
        self.response.out.write(html)
```

When I tried to check if variable extract is transferred correctly, I got an empty page. It seems like this variable is ignored...  The whole framework seems fine if I feed extract with a number. So could anyone help me to identify if my approach is correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code does not handle escaping HTML correctly. Additionally, it is a `text` field rather than a `hidden` field:

```
$('.getpdf').append('<tr style="display:none"><td><input name="extract" value="' + jq_html + '"></input></td></tr>');
```

A better way to do it would be like this:

```
$('<tr style="display:none"><td><input type="hidden" name="extract"></td></tr>')
    .appendTo('.getpdf')
    .find('input')
    .val(jq_html);
```

Comment: would you mind taking a look at this question? It is about escape data url in html. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651477/convert-a-jqplot-figure-into-data-url-and-send-as-part-of-html-form