# Convert a jqplot figure into data url and send as part of html form

Tags: jquery, html, jqplot

I have a dynamic figure which is generated by jqplot. Now I need to pass this plot to another webpage in the PNG format. My solution is

1. Convert this jqplot as data url in a variable

   ```
   var imgData = $('#chart1').jqplotToImageStr({});
   ```
2. Send this variable as part of html form to the next page

   ```
   $('<tr style="display:none"><td><input type="hidden" name="extract1"></td></tr>')
       .appendTo('.getpdf')
       .find('input')
       .data(imgData);
   ```

   I also tried to use `.val(imgData)`, which also failed
3. Print it and check.

   extract1 = form.getvalue('extract1')

   html = html + """'<'img id="imgChart1" src="%s" />"""%(extract2)

However, on the next page, when I tried to print this variable, I got nothing. It seems like it did escape this variable properly. If I assign `extract2` with data-url string, it worked. Could anyone give me some suggestions?

#### Update:

It seems like the problem existed in the step sending image as data-url to the next page. In the new page, if I supply a verified image data-url, it worked.

Comment: Are you sure `imgData` contains anything? Try adding `alert(imgData)` after you set it.

Comment: @icktoofay: Thanks for taking a look at this. Yes. In my console, I had `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg....`

Comment: @icktoofay: it worked! I have to use .val(imgData); Thanks again